# Are any implementations of Bloomier filters available?

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, bloom-filter

I've come across quite a bit of theory regarding [Bloomier filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloomier_filter#Bloomier_filters) but have had no luck digging up an actual implementation of them (no luck at github, sourceforge, google, etc.).  Does anyone know of an implementation available for use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No implementation appeared to be available, so I made a first pass at one.  I have posted it on [github](https://github.com/egrim/java-bloomier-filter) for anyone else that might find it interesting or useful.  Suggestions and patches are most welcome, so feel free to get involved!

Answer (score 2):

The Bloom filter topic just came up on the [boost mailing list](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/220699)

There's a link to an implementation in the boost sandbox.

A while back, there was another discussion linking to http://cplusplus-soup.com/2009/06/08/bloom-filters/

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, but please note that I'm looking for boom_ier_ filter implementations - a related, but distinct, concept.

Comment: @Evan: since you mention working together, you could contact the person currently working on the Bloom filter project that Ralf reported about...

Comment: @Evan, ok, wasn't aware of the distinction :) just coincidentally saw the post on the ML this morning. Perhaps follow Francesco's advice?

Answer (score 1):

A presumably simper Python implementation inspired by the Java one from @evan-grim.

https://github.com/wdwind/bloomier_filter